# Error 1 Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SourceProject.exe" to "bin\Debug

Tags: visual-studio-2013, error-handling

This is a super weird question for Visual Studio 2013: Windows Forms Application 3.5!

I designed and made the program, then I ran the program for the first time and an error pops up.
And then I click cancel, retry and this time I click yes and this pops up:

> Error while trying to run project: Could not load file or assembly
>   'SourceProject' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's
>   manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.(Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Any ideas on fixing it?
**FULL ERROR LOG**

> Error 1   Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\SOURCEPROJECT.exe" to
>   "bin\Debug\SOURCEPROJECT.exe". Access to the path
>   'obj\Debug\SOURCEPROJECT.exe' is denied.  SOURCEPROJECT

Comment: You need to get your machine stable again.  The 99% case is your anti-malware, make an exclusion.  If it is Avast then get rid of it completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just open your Debug Configuration near by Application Run Button in VS. Then , Choose debug with Any CPU to x64 or x86 .. May be it will help someone.

Thanks,

Comment: Umm... okay.. might as well Mark your answer correct, but you should try and help others out instead of trying to answer years-old questions.